# How to get flash to float above website?

Tags: html, css, flash, layout

What I have is a flash media player, and I want this to float on top of our forum such that when a user scrolls down, the media player follows.

I have yet to find a way to make it sit above html. It always pushes it down.

You can see the media player I am talking about at http://www.gcehosting.com/stackoverflow

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Music Player Widget - Preview 2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #000000;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="flashContent">

            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="main" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="main.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />

                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="main.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <param name="movie" value="main.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would love for someone to be able to provide a solution

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please take some time to review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `wmode` parameter to `transparent`, which makes all non-object areas of your SWF see-through. Then use absolute CSS positioning to put it on top of anywhere in your web page.

Relevant code snippets from [this tutorial](http://animation.about.com/od/flashanimationtutorials/ss/flashwmode.htm#showall):

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 900;
  height: 900;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <object>
    <param name="movie" value="dummy.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="dummy.swf" wmode="transparent">
  </object>
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask why you do not recomment it?

Comment: google for `flash wmode bug` => for example http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/08/29/the-wmode-nightmare-in-flex-some-workarounds-to-resolve-issues-pertaining-to-wmode-settings-in-flex/

Comment: "Transparent flash that follows" immediately reminds me of annoying advertisements that get in my way when I want to read or click on links. You're using it for a different purpose, so it's okay. My bad.

Comment: I hate flash adverts. I will not put a single advert on any of my 7 sites. Not even my free web hosting site. I'd rather make no money than have those intrusive things there

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` on `#flashContent`, set it to `right:0`, and ensure the width/height isn't covering the forum.

Comment: ok Ikinda get what you are saying. So with width/height what do I make it?

Comment: dunno, whatever the width/height is necessary to display the flash content. maybe around 200px width?

Comment: Problem is: If I leave it 100x100 you can not click anything on the forum. If I change it to say 30% then what happens is the player ends up on the left aof the page.......

Comment: If you got the url I provided I have it showing correctly although this is a test and is iframe the forum, I tried it live on the forum and got the same results